# how to communicate easily to parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using angular directives to create a little complex form.

```
<div class="row">

     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span></span>
     </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8" ng-controller="newOrdercontroller" >
        <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="checkvalues(order)">
            <div id="items-container">
                <new-generic-item item-type="ecommerce" deletable="false" item-id="1"></new-generic-item>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addElement($event)">Add Item</button>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" ></button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

evidently, `new-generic-item` is the directive i'm using. This directive creates multiple form elements.

```
    .directive("newGenericItem", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'static/js/directives/genericItem.html',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var itemType = $attrs['itemType'];
            var itemId = $attrs['itemId'];
            var deletable = $attrs['deletabe'];

            $scope.items = $scope.itemTypes[itemType];

        },
        scope:true
    }
})
```

this produces the following form.
[image]

so with `Add Item` button I managed to add the multiple directives.

[image]

this is the reason why i used `scope:true` in my directive factory.

The problem comes with this using of different scopes. I am having a hard time submitting the form. What would be the easiest way to access all the values of this form.

I have come simple solutions where in directive is used to create single simple form-element. (http://jsfiddle.net/revolunet/9e7Hy/)

My situation is different as it involves multiple form elements.

incase, having the controller code is useful

```
.controller('newOrdercontroller', function($scope, $compile,  itemTypes){
        $scope.itemTypes = itemTypes;
        $scope.addElement = function(event){
            var element = angular.element(document.querySelector("#items-container"));
            element.append($compile('<new-generic-item item-type="ecommerce"></new-generic-item>')($scope));
        }

        $scope.checkvalues = function(order){
            console.log($scope);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not manipulate DOM directly when u can avoid it.
2. You have several properties, why not put them into object.
3. If u use isolated scope - access variables correctly, not throw attributes (which do not give u binding by default). So in the end:

> ```
> <new-generic-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></new-generic-item>
> <button ng-click="addNewItem()">Add</button>
> ```

in controller:
$scope.items = [{type: ..., id: ...}];
    $scope.addNewItem = function() {
      $scope.items.push({new object});
    }
In directive:

```
scope: { item : '='}
```

Add just use 'item' in template, like

> `<input ng-model="item.type">`

Then in submit you have all your data in array and can easily do whatever you want.

Comment: you are missing something here, actually it's my fault, itemTypes is huge dictionary which comes from the controller. If set scope to be like this i cannot access this and then I have to set this on every new-generic-item which makes it ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Using events :

Example... Child scope:

```
$scope.$emit('runApplication', parameters);
```

On one of your ancestors scope (definitely sure that is not your parent )
Actually I don't know what's in par2, maybe the scope of the directive firing the event. It's still some test code :)

```
$scope.$on('runApplication', function(par2, parameters) {

});
```